# Let $G$ be a group and $g,h \in G$. If $\phi_g = \phi_h$, prove that $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$, where $\phi_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $g,h \in G$. If $\phi_g = \phi_h$, prove that
> $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$.

Attempt:
Given $g \in G$, $\phi_g = \phi_{\epsilon}$ if $g$ is in the center because that would mean $gxg^{-1} = x \implies gx=xg$ which is the definition of the center.
So then assuming $\phi_g = \phi_h \implies \phi_{h^{-1}}\phi_g = \phi_{{h^{-1}}g} = \phi_{\epsilon}$. From the previous result, this means $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$.

Edit: $\phi_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$

Is this correct?

Comment: The previous result?

Comment: You should also mention $\phi_g$ refers to the function $\phi_g(x):=gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: @Michael As in Given $g \in G, \phi_g = \phi_e$ if $g$ is in the center $Z(G)$.

Comment: Yeah, I will mention that mapping.

Comment: If by "the previous result" you mean the first sentence of your attempt, then note that you are invoking it backwards: you show that if $g$ is in the center then $\phi_g=\phi_e$, but you are invoking it to claim that if $\phi_g=\phi_e$ then $g$ is in the center. That is not what you showed, so you cannot invoke it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite some number of gaps, which may be the previous results of your text.

First, I believe that you are talking about the function $\phi:G\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ defined by $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$.

If $\phi_g=\phi_{\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon$ is the identity of $G$, then $gxg^{-1}=\epsilon g\epsilon^{-1}=g$ for all $x\in G$ and therefore $g\in Z(G)$.

Note that $\phi_{h^{-1}g}=\phi^{-1}_{h}\phi_g$ because $\phi$ is a homomorphism. And also as $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we get $\phi_{\epsilon}=\iota$, the identity map of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Therefore, the assumption $\phi_g=\phi_h$ implies $$\phi_{h^{-1}g}=\phi^{-1}_{h}\phi_g=\iota=\phi_{\epsilon}.$$
By the previous paragraph, this concludes that $h^{-1}g\in Z(G)$.